# unknown override specifier in CString?

Tags: c++11, visual-c++

I have created a class and having CString data member.

```
class Clistof
{
CString m_exe;
public:
Clistof(CString temp){m_exe = temp}
};
```

error : C3646 'exe': unknown override specifier

Any idea ?

Thanks,

Comment: `exe` is not found in the code you provided. You should give real information! (for example, what is the line of code for which the compiler is complaining?

Answer (score 0):

You probably did not include a header that contains the definition for `CString`. Try including `#include <atlstr.h>` if you haven't done so already.

Also, please note that you forgot to add a `;` after the assignment statement in your constructor: instead of `Clistof(CString temp){m_exe = temp}` you should write `Clistof(CString temp) { m_exe = temp; }`.